# Why the figure plotted by my code only shows the blank?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the attachment of the python code:

```
    from scipy.stats import norm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import math
    def V(S0):
    # nx = norm.cdf(x)
    K = 1.5
    T = 1
    sigma = 0.1
    rd = 0.03
    ry = 0.02
    e = math.e
    d1 = (math.log((S0 * e ** ((rd - ry) * T)) / K) + (sigma ** 2 * T) / 2) / (sigma * math.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (math.log((S0 * e ** ((rd - ry) * T)) / K) - (sigma ** 2 * T) / 2) / (sigma * math.sqrt(T))
    nd1 = norm.cdf(d1)
    nd2 = norm.cdf(d2)
    V = e ** (-rd * T) * (S0 * e ** ((rd - ry) * T) * nd1 - K * nd2)
V2 = np.vectorize(V)
S0 = np.arange(1, 1000, 1)
plt.title('V as a function of S0')
plt.xlabel('S0')
plt.ylabel('V')
plt.plot(S0, V2(S0))
plt.show()
```

And the code with such a result:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are two issues

  1. `math.log` only accepts size-1 arrays

     - Removed the `math` module and switched to `numpy` methods
  2. Nothing is returned by the function `V`

     - Added `return V`

```py
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def V(S0):
    # nx = norm.cdf(x)
    K = 1.5
    T = 1
    sigma = 0.1
    rd = 0.03
    ry = 0.02
    e = np.e
    d1 = (np.log((S0 * e ** ((rd - ry) * T)) / K) + (sigma ** 2 * T) / 2) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (np.log((S0 * e ** ((rd - ry) * T)) / K) - (sigma ** 2 * T) / 2) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
    nd1 = norm.cdf(d1)
    nd2 = norm.cdf(d2)
    V = e ** (-rd * T) * (S0 * e ** ((rd - ry) * T) * nd1 - K * nd2)
    return V  # return V added

V2 = np.vectorize(V)
S0 = np.arange(1, 1000, 1)
plt.title('V as a function of S0')
plt.xlabel('S0')
plt.ylabel('V')
plt.plot(S0, V2(S0))
plt.show()
```

[image]